# RAID 6 with XFS dealing with bad sectors

Tags: xfs, badblocks

I have 7 2tb hdd in a raid 6 attached to a Adaptec 71685

dmesg message says I have bad sectors

> 2321236720 2321236728 2321236760 2321236792 2321236824 2321236856
>   2321236864 2329211680 2329212192 2329212704 2329212872 2329213384
>   2329225888 2329226400 2329226408 2329226920 2329227432 2701810832
>   2701811344 2701811856 2701812368

xfs_repair -L /dev/sdc1

with repair the filesystem, but when I write more data to the RAID the errors resurface.

```
[  703.888787] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 42 f8 00 00 00 80 00 00
[  704.542375] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 42 f8 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.543095] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 08 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.543791] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 18 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.544477] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 28 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.668617] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 38 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.669118] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 48 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.669558] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 58 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  704.672910] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#1 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 68 00 00 00 10 00 00
[  711.364409] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 42 f8 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  711.365047] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  711.365633] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  711.366210] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 10 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  711.366704] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 8a 5b 43 18 00 00 00 08 00 00
```

Attempted a verify with fix on the Adaptec 71685, and it says everything is fine.

I have several TB of data which I would rather not re-download from cloud backup because it would be sloooow.

I don't care if the bad sectors are just hidden, chkdsk style.  If I knew which hdd those sectors are on, I could use the adaptec built in tool, but scanning all 7 drives is way to slow.

SMART on the adaptec controller only shows a few (as many as 24) CRC errors, and all other error metrics are 0 across 7 drives.  A couple drives have aborted commands, but the highest number is 581 and it hasn't increased.

I decided to run badblocks -b 65536 -s -v -o /badblocks.txt /dev/sdc1

The default block size of 1024 said there were more blocks and than a 32 bit integer can handle so I used 65536.

At 14.14% it claims 140 errors.  How can I tell xfs about this list?  Can I somehow force the adaptec 71685 to deal with these errors.